# Emacs error "error in process filter wrong type argument arrayp nil"

Tags: python, emacs, cedet

### when I use emacs24.4 to edit python code, it show the error. this is my error information.(my python in gentoo is 3.3)

I have found the problem is due to my cedet. My cedet-2.0 is built in to emacs, this is my .emacs about cedet

```
; turn on Semantic
(semantic-mode 1)
(defun my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete() 
(add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-semantic))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my:add-semantic-to-autocomplete)
```

My -debug-init information,

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument keymapp py-down-exception)
keymap-parent(py-down-exception)
keymap-parent(py-down-exception)



python-shell-make-comint("/usr/bin/python -i" "Python Internal [79d43858819f96a64f0c016c9df91396]" nil t)
  run-python-internal()
python-shell-internal-get-or-create-process()

  python-shell-internal-send-string("import sys;print ('\\n'.join(sys.path))")
  semantic-python-get-system-include-path()
  (progn (semantic-python-get-system-include-path))
  (if (and (featurep (quote python)) (not noninteractive)) (progn (semantic-python-get-system-include-path)))
  (when (and (featurep (quote python)) (not noninteractive)) (semantic-python-get-system-include-path))
  eval((when (and (featurep (quote python)) (not noninteractive)) (semantic-python-get-system-include-path)))
  byte-code("\303\304N\211\203  @\202\n)!\207" [symbol sv exp eval saved-value] 4)
  custom-initialize-reset(semantic-python-dependency-system-include-path (when (and (featurep (quote python)) (not noninteractive)) (semantic-python-get-system-include-path)))
  custom-declare-variable(semantic-python-dependency-system-include-path (when (and (featurep (quote python)) (not noninteractive)) (semantic-python-get-system-include-path)) "The system include path used by Python language." :group python :group semantic :type (repeat (directory :tag "Directory")) :set #[(sym val) "\303  \"\210  \304\305\nBC\306\307#\210\310\311\307\"\210\n\210)\312\313!\205\"\310\313\307\"\207" [sym val tmp0 set-default mode-local-bind semantic-dependency-system-include-path (mode-variable-flag t) python-mode mode-local-map-mode-buffers #[nil "\302\301!\210\211\207" [tmp0 semantic-dependency-system-include-path make-local-variable] 2] fboundp semantic-decoration-unparsed-include-do-reset] 4])
  byte-code("\306\300\307\310\311\312\311\313\314\315\316\317&\210\320\321  BC\322\323#\210\324\325\323\"\210   \210)\326\321\323\327!\330\n\204F\211\204F \205E\331
\"\n\203p\f\204p\n\332N\203_\331
\n\332N\"\211\204F\n\211\333N\206j\n\334N)\211\204J\f,\335\336#\210\326\321\323\300#\207" [semantic-python-dependency-system-include-path tmp0 mode symbol bind name custom-declare-variable (when (and (featurep (quote python)) (not noninteractive)) (semantic-python-get-system-include-path)) "The system include path used by Python language." :group python semantic :type (repeat (directory :tag "Directory")) :set #[(sym val) "\303 \"\210  \304\305\nBC\306\307#\210\310\311\307\"\210\n\210)\312\313!\205\"\310\313\307\"\207" [sym val tmp0 set-default mode-local-bind semantic-dependency-system-include-path (mode-variable-flag t) python-mode mode-local-map-mode-buffers #[nil "\302\301!\210\211\207" [tmp0 semantic-dependency-system-include-path make-local-variable] 2] fboundp semantic-decoration-unparsed-include-do-reset] 4] mode-local-bind semantic-dependency-system-include-path (mode-variable-flag t) python-mode mode-local-map-mode-buffers #[nil "\302\301!\210\211\207" [tmp0 semantic-dependency-system-include-path make-local-variable] 2] put symbol-name nil intern-soft mode-local-symbol-table mode-local-parent derived-mode-parent variable-documentation "System path to search for include files." mode-local-active-mode major-mode] 12)
  wisent-python-default-setup()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook python-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook python-mode-hook))
  run-mode-hooks(python-mode-hook)
  python-mode()


    set-auto-mode-0(python-mode nil)
      set-auto-mode()
      normal-mode(t)
      after-find-file(nil t)
      find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer test.py> "~/Code/python/test.py" nil nil "~/Code/python/test.py" (20716135 2051))



find-file-noselect("~/Code/python/test.py" nil nil t)



find-file("~/Code/python/test.py" t)



call-interactively(find-file nil nil)



command-execute(find-file)
```